# php regex vsprintf addign slash on file extension

Tags: php, regex, printf

I have a problem with the following piece of code: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HkY6n211). For example:

```
/^\/index\.php\/index\/home\/(\w+)$/
```

It adds a slash before the .php extension. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please post the code here, not on some 3rd party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you pass that example as the uri I see that on line 10 you have `preg_quote($uri)`. That should be the reason. Since dot (.) has a meaning in Regex the function is escaping it.

But that is what you want I believe since if you strip that slash your regex will match ANY character instead of the dot (including the dot). So any of these will be valid:

```
indexBphp
index-php
indexmphp
index.php
etc...
```

Dot in Regex means match any character at this position. So I believe that there is nothing wrong, right?

One way to fix this if you still want to have that dot there is to build the regex in two separate parts:

```
$urlDivided = explode('.php', $url);
$this->finalRegex = preg_quote($urlDivided[0]) . '.php' . preg_quote($urlDivided[1]);
```

Obviously, the method above assumes that you always have the '.php' extension in the url. You should do sanity checks.

Comment: A solution would like i would always remove the index.php from url :-) or rethink the entire code.